# Networks, Plot only Top N edges for a node based on edges values in python

Tags: networkx

I have Created graph from data frame  using pandas correlation function  , But I only want to plot graph such that , each node should have only top 5 edges (based on edges values) 
plus there should not be a cutoff limit specified,  can this possible .

```
def data_corelation_network_grid_layout(file):

    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    correlation = df.corr()
    #correlation.to_csv('D:\Thesis\Constant sampled Data_correaltion_revised.csv')

    links = correlation.stack().reset_index()

    #print(links)
    links.columns = ['var1', 'var2', 'value']


    links_filtered=links.loc[ (links['var1'] != links['var2']) ]


    G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(links_filtered, 'var1', 'var2')



    for i in range(11):
        for j in range (11):
            if ((G.has_edge('{}{}'.format("p", i),'{}{}'.format("p", j))) ):
                G.remove_edge('{}{}'.format("p", i),'{}{}'.format("p", j))
            elif(G.has_edge('{}{}'.format("q", i),'{}{}'.format("q", j))):
                G.remove_edge('{}{}'.format("q", i), '{}{}'.format("q", j))



    g = G.to_directed()



    pos = nx.spring_layout(g, k=0.5*1/np.sqrt(len(G.nodes())), iterations=20)

    plt.figure(3, figsize=(30, 30))
    nx.draw(g, pos=pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos=pos,arrows=True)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to iterate over rows (or columns) of your correlation matrix and set all values in a row that are not in the top 5 for that row to 0.

Comment: Thanks , I did that already, but was wondering was any way to do the same in networks such that it selects top n values and then plot it

Comment: There is no ready made function in `networkx` that draws just the most "important" edges in a network, if that is what you are asking.